# Structure of a mapping comes from the Codomain?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that:
>
> If $A$ is a non empty set and $R$ a ring, then $\operatorname{map}(A,R)$, is a ring too, with the following operations:
>
> $f+g$ is defined by: $(f+g)(x):=f(x)+g(x)$ for all $x\in A$
>
> $f\cdot g$ is defined by: $(f\cdot g)(x):= f(x)\cdot g(x)$ for all $x\in A$

I am stuck at the very first step, showing that $f(x)+g(x)$ is an element of $\operatorname{map}(A,R)$.

Could you give me the tools, apart from the definitions, to prove this on my own?

Also is there a more elegant way than "axiom"-checking?

$\operatorname{map}(A,R)$ is the set of all functions from $A$ to $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not $f(x)+g(x)$, but $h=f+g$, with $h:A\rightarrow R$ such as $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)\in R$ by the properties of the ring for $x\in A$.